# React Running the code Before State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new with React and ES6,I have a component like This:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Order = () => {
    let username='Test',password = 'secret';
    const [Data,setData]=useState({title:'',submit:false});
    const [List,setList]=useState({title:'',submit:false});
    const Clicked = ()=>{
        if(username==='Test'){
            setData({title:'Yes',submit:true});
        }
        else{
            setData({title:'No',submit:false});
        }
        if(password==='secret'){
            setList({title:'Yes',submit:true});
        }
        else{
            setList({title:'No',submit:false});
        }
        console.log(Data.submit,List.submit);
        if(Data.submit && List.submit){
            alert('Time to Submit')
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={Clicked}>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Order;
```

My Problem is when I click the Button , the `Data.submit` and `List.submit` is considered both False at first click,but in second click they both gets true and it alerts `alert('Time to Submit')`.
Because I'm using Data and List for two different Buttons,I cannot use `useEffect()`.
I don't want the user to click twice.How could I approach this?

Comment: What about `useCallback`? Also, why can't you use `useEffect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Order = () => {
  let username = "Test",
    password = "secret";
  const [Data, setData] = useState({ title: "", submit: false });
  const [List, setList] = useState({ title: "", submit: false });
  const Clicked = () => {
    let dataSubmit, listSubmit;
    if (username === "Test") {
      dataSubmit = true;
      setData({ title: "Yes", submit: true });
    } else {
      setData({ title: "No", submit: false });
    }
    if (password === "secret") {
      listSubmit = true;
      setList({ title: "Yes", submit: true });
    } else {
      setList({ title: "No", submit: false });
    }
    if (dataSubmit && listSubmit) {
      alert("Time to Submit");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={Clicked}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly because the set state is asynchronous, therefore if you call like synchronous code it won't work as expected.

To solve this issue you can do the following:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Order = () => {
    let username='Test',password = 'secret';
    const [Data,setData]=useState({title:'',submit:false});
    const [List,setList]=useState({title:'',submit:false});
    const Clicked = ()=>{
        const data = {title: '', submit: false};
        const list = {title: '', submit: false};

        if(username==='Test'){
            data.title = 'Yes';
            data.submit = true;
        }
        else{
            data.title = 'No';
            data.submit = false;
        }
        if(password==='secret'){
            list.title = 'Yes';
            list.submit = true;
        }
        else{
            list.title = 'No';
            list.submit = false;
        }
        console.log(Data.submit,List.submit);
        if(data.submit && list.submit){
            alert('Time to Submit')
        }
        setData(data);
        setList(list);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={Clicked}>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Order;
```

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous (React will decide when to apply the changes for improved performance), at the time you log to the console the state hasn't changed yet. If you don't want to use `useEffect` to detect when the state has changed you can use the variables you already have in the function

```
    const Clicked = ()=>{
        if(username==='Test'){
            setData({title:'Yes',submit:true});
        }
        else{
            setData({title:'No',submit:false});
        }
        if(password==='secret'){
            setList({title:'Yes',submit:true});
        }
        else{
            setList({title:'No',submit:false});
        }
        if(username==='Test' && password==='secret'){
            alert('Time to Submit')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` callbacks are asynchronous from my intuition that's why the logging outputs the unchanged version of the data. @Nishant's solution above should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, I added comments to make it clear, I you hace any question don't hesitate asking me. (Ps, I'm not a native speaker so sorry because of my english)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const Order = () => {
        let username='Test',password = 'secret';
        //fist of all, I recomend you to call your useState variables
        //always using lowercase becase if you name it uppercase
        //it means that is a component o a class
        const [data, setData]=useState({title:'',submit:false});
        const [list, setList]=useState({title:'', submit:false});

        //I also recomment to call you functions using camelCase using the first letter with lowercase
        const clicked = ()=>{
          // I created a couple variables to improve readability and help with logic
          const correctUsername = username === 'Test' //this will return true if username equal test, otherwise will return false;
          const correctPassword = password === 'secret'; //same here

          //Here, you can use a ternary, that is the same as is else, but in a short way
          // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator
          setData(correctUsername ? {title: 'Yes', submit: true} : {title: 'No', submit: false});
          setList(correctPassword ? {title: 'Yes', submit: true} : {title: 'No', submit: false});
        }

        
    //You can use an useEffect to watch stateChanges
        useEffect(()=>{
          if(data.submit && list.submit){
            console.log({data, list})
            alert('Time to Submit')
            }
          },[data, list]) 

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={clicked}>Click</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default Order;
```